# 2 layer PCB grounding

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, ground

I have a 2 layer PCB that contains an ESP32, a LoRa module, a GSM module, some connectors to command relays and 3.3V & 5V power rails. My question is, should I set both layers as ground planes or set the bottom layer as GND plane and on the top layer I make 3V and 5V polygons. What is the best way to do?[image]

Comment: Some more details may help - anything high power? Any sensitive analog? RF? Mixed-signal? Particularly stringent requirements for either emissions or noise immunity? What does your board do? Please [edit] your post to add this info, as opposed to replying in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

By convention, most signals are thought of as being relative to ground, although this is only a convention and there’s nothing that makes the integrity of the ‘low’ supply rail any more important than the ‘high’ rail; the important thing is to keep the voltages stable relative to each other.  Where DC current is moderate and transient currents are dominant, decoupling capacitors can provide good voltage stability.  So in many cases it would be just as valid to use a 3.3 or 5V plane.  As a practical solution though, you’ll want to have the lowest impedance you can for every rail; your suggestion of using polygons and a ground plane is a sound one.

Answer (score 1):

On a PCB, copper is free, so setting one layer as ground plane doesn't cost extra, and it is better for signal integrity.

That said, the datasheets of your radio modules probably mention something about clearance between the onboard antennas and nearby metallic objects, like ground planes, metal enclosure, etc.

If the modules sit on 0.1" sockets, they should sit almost 1cm high from the board, so that should be okay. ESP32 works fine on a socket over a ground plane. But if you don't use sockets, and solder them directly, the antennas could be too close to the ground plane.

Comment: Is it bad to set the 2 layers as ground planes , and why ?

Comment: Where do you put traces if both layers are ground ?